# how to get the value of all elements with a certain class

Tags: jquery

I have a list (li) of items, and on click, I want to get the value of each item that has a specific class. Then add them to an array.

```
<ul id="list">
<li value="1" class="selected">One</li>
<li value="2">Two</li>
<li value="3" class="selected">Three</li>
</ul>

$('#list li').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    values = new array();
    each(function(){
    if('#list li').hasClass('selected') {
    values[] = $('#list li').val();
}
    });
});
```

So what we are doing, is taking all the values of the list elements that contain the class "selected" and adding them to an array. So in the above example we would want the end result to be a variable with an array(1,3). And can that variable be passed through ajax? Or would it need to equal just 1,3 as a string?

Comment: `values = $('#list li.selected').map(function(i,elem){ return this.value}).toArray();`

Comment: Only form elements have a `value` property. List items do not. Try using data attributes instead and [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: I think he has a custom attribute `value` for each `li`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.map()` method. The variable `value` is an array with all the values of `li` elements with `selected` class:

```
$('#list li').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var values = $('#list li.selected').map(function(i,v) {
        return v.value;
    }).get();    
});
```

If a `li` already has the class, it wont be removed:

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/XNm3P/)

But if you substitute `.toggleClass()` for `.addClass()` here is how it works:

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/XNm3P/1/)

Comment: Yes, if that's what your intention was; otherwise once added the class remains for good. Would you like me to edit my answer?

Comment: what are the arguments i,v for, in function(i,v), and what is .get() for?

Comment: Also what would it be if I wanted a string instead of array?

Comment: i and v are the index and current DOM element in the iteration. I would check the jQuery .map API documentation for the .get() part but all I know is that you have to use it when using .map on DOM elements. To get a string/list just use ...get().join(',')